# Kato's log motives

Tags: motives, log-geometry

What are they and what are their intended uses? Does anyone have notes/slides of [this](http://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/seminars/showseminars.php?sem=90) talk?

I am curious about "log motives" because there seems to exist a "log motivic yoga" among experts in arithmetic geometry, but I could find only a few short hints and no available exposition or survey. E.g. in Asterisque 223, Fontaine lists a text about them in the bibl. of his artcles, Niziol mentions them shortly in her p-adic semi-stability conjecture (a p-adic analogon of Grothendieck's l-adic local monodromy theorem).

Comment: What does your second sentence mean?

Comment: If someone has slides of that talk by Kato or notes explaining what "log motives" are, I'd be happy if I could read them. Of course I would be equally happy for any other explanation.  

Comment: It would help the rest of us if you expanded the text of your question.  For example, you might like to tell us a little about motives without log structures, or log structures on varieties over a field.  Also, instead of just pointing to a talk and asking for notes, you could start with something like, "Kato gave a talk on motives and log motives.  Could someone tell me what one is and why one would study them?"

Comment: To SC: I am among new members in MO and tried to be acive in last couple of weeks. It is a great resource. But I can say that the often-seen police statements against the questioners are what makes me double think wheather to help this community or freeze my activity. For example this question makes perfect sense to me. It gives some pointers to specific sources. It is pretty unambigous Q to anybody who knows a bit both about either motives or log schemes. For those who don't the COMBINATION is hopeless to attempt if we need to start as far as what is log geometry. Google would do better. 